# How to load and find the ID for a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.2. I have 3 Models. Mom, Dad and Follows. Follow is polymorphic and can belong to a mom or a dad.

```
class Dad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
end

class Mom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :follows, as: :followable
end

class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
end
```

My routes:

```
  resources :dads do
    resources :follows
  end

  resources :moms do
    resources :follows
  end
```

Now in my Follows controller I want to load associations needed:

```
FollowsController

private
  def load_followable
    klass = [Dad, Mom].detect { |f| params["#{f.name.underscore}_id"]}
    @followable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
  end
end
```

But this throws this error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Because of `@followable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])`

OK, so it seems in order to make `klass` not be `nil` I have to have something in the controller or the view? I want to show all the mom and dad follows on my index page. This still throws an error:

```
FollowsController
 before_action :load_followable

 index
  @follows = @followable.follows
 end
```

How is this done?

Comment: your klass is nil, so klass.name throws this error?

Comment: Can you do a binding.pry on the method and see if klass is nil?

Comment: I don't get it, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I think D.fux answer was where I was trying to get. The real problem is your parameters. They don't contain mom_id or dad_id

Comment: There's a `Follow` instance in your `FollowsController`, something like `@follow = Follow.find(params[:id])`, right?

Comment: @user2784630 Can you show us how your request params arrive in the controller please?

Comment: I'm sorry, i think i didn't express me well. Would you show us what the params variable contains?

Comment: @paulorcdiniz If your talking about the `index` variable `@follows = @followable.follows`. The `@follows` I can't get to because I have to do the `before_action :load_followable` which is the problem I'm having in the first place.

Comment: No, i meant the params variable. If you do a binding.pry on your load_followable method and a 'puts parms' it will print out the params variable

Comment: @paulorcdiniz `[1] pry(#<FollowsController>)> puts params
{"controller"=>"follows", "action"=>"index"}
=> nil
`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the *params* doesn't contain both *dad_id* and *mom_id*. So the *detect* method returns **nil** to **klass**. Maybe you should check your View to confirm that any form submits an id of dad or mom indeed?

---

If you want to show all the records, you should not use the `load_followable` as it needs the front page to post parameters to your controller. What you may need to do is only to call the `all` method on your ActiveRecord:

```
FollowsController
#before_action :load_followable

 index
  @follows = Follow.all
 end
```

`@follows` will be an array of all your follows. For each follow in it, `follow.followable` will return a dad or mom that associates with it.

Comment: Params must have one of `dad_id` or `mom_id`. Sure enough, the debug output shows `params` doesn't contain either.